# ERROR: Parsing unable to continue due to merge conflicts in Podfile.lock

Tags: xcode, error-handling, cocoapods, merge-conflict-resolution, podfile

recently since updating Xcode i have big troubles using podfiles. 
I wasn't able to add any new pods to my existing pod file, hence i decide to create a new project and just copy all my stuff inside. But now I have to face the same issues again and i would be really happy if we were able to solve this.

As the title says i get the following error every time i try to use pod install or any other pod commands:

ERROR: Parsing unable to continue due to merge conflicts present in:
the file located at /Users/Al/Xcode/Alpha/Podfile.lock

and at the end of the whole error log it says:

<<<<<<< HEAD

PODFILE CHECKSUM: ee6160c5c3b5d0c8ebc5ddcb9ac0841413b85dc3

=======

PODFILE CHECKSUM: d5cfd70801e862e4ade36c54ca4ad6698be59373

D>>>>>>> 41bfa2c75e2c2a1832f998baf7bd445e385ba513

COCOAPODS: 1.3.1

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you don't need to insure you keep previous versions of any Pods, remove the Podfile.lock file and then do a fresh `pod install`:

```
rm /Users/Al/Xcode/Alpha/Podfile.lock
pod install
```

Comment: It was almost the solution but only removing pod file.lock didn't do all because it calls a merge error in manifest.lock then. This file i found inside the folder pods where all pods are saved in after deleting the whole folder and then installing pods worked. Thanks!

Comment: Can we set merge strategy for a specific file, such as the Podfile.lock?

Comment: disagree. this solution will lead to scenario "why the app runs on my computer with error but you not" because of mismatching pod versions on 2 devices

Comment: This worked for me. Much appreciated @Paul Beusterien